# Detect lowest value from user input in Python 3.6

Tags: python, min

I have to calculate the average grade for a set of values based on user input, while dropping the lowest grade before calculating the average. I have everything except for the code to drop the lowest value. I tried using the min function, but when printed inside the loop I get "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable." Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

```
numuser=eval(input("How many users are there?: "))
numgrade=eval(input("How many grades will there be for each user?: "))
usercount=0
gradecount=0

while usercount <= numuser:
    name=input("Please enter the user's first and last name: ")
    gradetot=0
    while gradecount < numgrade:
        gradeval=eval(input("Please enter the grade: "))
        gradetot=gradetot+gradeval
        gradecount=gradecount+1

low = min(gradeval)
tot = gradetot-low

print("The average grade for", name, "is :", tot/gradecount)
numuser=numuser-1
usercount=usercount+1
gradecount=0
```

Comment: Don't use `eval()`! Use `int()` to convert to an integer.

Comment: As for your problem. If you want to use `min()` to get the lowest grade you need to make a list. You're resetting `gradeeval` as an integer through the loop. Alternatively you could use another variable and set it each time if it's lower than the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I make it a list if the numbers are dependent on the user input? (Sorry if this is a dumb question, first time ever coding!)

Comment: Never mind, got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your application please see below and try to understand what change needed to fulfil your requirement.

```
numuser=eval(input("How many users are there : " ))
numgrade=eval(input("How many grades will there be for each user : " ))
usercount=0
gradecount=0
gradeval = [] # you need a array to store a range of values

while usercount <= numuser:
    name=input("Please enter the user's first and last name : " )
    gradetot=0
    while gradecount < numgrade:
        val=eval(input("Please enter the grade :  " ))
        gradeval.append(val)
        gradetot=gradetot+val
        gradecount=gradecount+1

low = min(gradeval)# min function need a range of values
tot = gradetot-low

print("The average grade for : ", name, "is : ", tot/gradecount)
numuser=numuser-1
usercount=usercount+1
gradecount=0
```